# Как запретить добавление нового вложенного списка jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Создаю дерево из списков. Сначала выделяю элемент, к которому хочу добавить вложенный дочерний список ul, потом нажимаю на +, задаю параметры и ОК. И на определенном этапе мне нужно создать проверку на вложенность, т.е. сколько уже вложенных списков существует. Если 4 - тогда запретить добавление нового (нажатие +).

Comment: Лучше не запретить нажатие `+`, а перед добавлением узнать, какой будет по счету уровень..если четвертый - то плюсы не отрисовывать вообще....а то отрисуете...юзер будет тыкать и не будет понимать - почему не добавляются новые....что за баг такой.......а так  у `ul` ставить аттрибут `data-level` в котором будет лежать цифра текущего уровня.... перед добавлением смотреть на него и ориентироваться уже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.